# How to find and repalce anchor tag link inside td in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working with wordpress,I want to change "url"(product link) of "product-image" in "cart" page,
So i have following code (dynamic)

```
<td class="product-name" data-title="Product">
<a href="abc.com/en/product/basic-c-organic/">Basic-C-Organic</a>
</td>
```

How can i change the url of this product with jquery,I tried with following code but not working,how can i do this ?

```
var product = $('.product-name').next("a").text();
```

Comment: Should be `$('.product-name').find("a")` since the link is a child of your td. And if you need to change the url, use `$('.product-name').find("a").attr("href","newUrl")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
var urlReplacement = $('.product-name a').text();
var url = $('.product-name a').attr("href");
var pathComponent = url.split('/');
pathComponent[ pathComponent.length-1 ] = urlReplacement;
url = pathComponent.join('/');
$('.product-name a').attr("href", url);
```

Running example:

```js
var urlReplacement = $('.product-name a').text();
var url = $('.product-name a').attr("href");
var pathComponent = url.split('/');
pathComponent[ pathComponent.length-1 ] = urlReplacement;
url = pathComponent.join('/');
$('.product-name a').attr("href", url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="product-name" data-title="Product">
<a href="abc.com/en/product/basic-c-organic">delat-Organic</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Note: Now based on the product name (link text), the link URL will change dynamically once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "find" the the a tag and the change the link with the .attr() of jquery

```
var product = $('.product-name').find("a").attr("href", "https://www.whatever-you-like.com");
```

Comment: no , i want to change according to product name (condition) because i have 3 different products, so kindly update your answer

Comment: You need to change the part "https://www.whatever-you-like.com" by yourself. Because in your original post you did not mentioned about something like this should happen in a loop or else indicating to that. I gave you a good starting point on how to achieve what you originally asked. If the original post from you is not what you are seeking help for, I would recommend to read this articel before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This answer solves the problem in your question. If your question was not accurate to your actual situation I would suggest marking this answer as correct and starting a new question, making sure to include ALL necessary details in the new question.